# is_page post_parent and cookie issue

Tags: wordpress, cookies

The first time a visitor visits the homepage a video is played and a cookie is set. When this cookie expires the video will popup again. on a certain page with it's parent pages this video should not play if this is the first time the visitor visits those pages or the cookie has expired. I'm using WordPress.

```
if (is_page('60') || $post->post_parent == '60' && (isset($_COOKIE['my_cookie']))) {
// Do not play video
} else {
// Play video
}
```

Kind regards

Comment: What isn't working? For example, are videos playing all the time (when they shouldn't) or do videos never play (when they should)?

Comment: Good question. The code above works on site.com/page60 (the video is not playing) but on site.com/page60/parentpage1 the videos is playing. On all parent pages to page60 the video should not play at all.. That's the issue. Hope I clarified more :)